# Failed to construct 'AudioContext': The hardware sample rate provided is outside the range

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Creating AudioContext fails with an error:

`The hardware sample rate provided (48000) is outside the range [3000, 384000]`

This happens on Chrome 60. Unfortunately I can not reproduce this myself on my local machine.

Is there any way to fix or avoid this error?

Comment: Weird... 48000 is **inside** the range [3000, 384000]... When I try to modify my own device's sampleRate it does work fine on chrome 60 (osX) for all 41, 48, 88.2, 96kHz and all bit depths... You should probably file a bug report to chromium, but you'd also probably need some info from the device on which it occurs.

Comment: Yes please file a bug report at crbug.com/new

Comment: Created a bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=754171, unfortunately could not provide much details there.